# Pretty print uptime given seconds and omit unnecessary strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, formatting, unit-conversion

Given an integer number of seconds, return a string which represents in human readable format the number of days/hours/minutes/seconds that are equivalent.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta                        

def GetTime(sec):
    d = datetime(1,1,1) + timedelta(seconds=sec)
    days = (d.day-1,'d',' ') if (d.day-1 > 0) else ('','','')
    hours = (d.hour, 'h', ' ') if (d.hour > 0) else ('', '', '')
    mins = (d.minute, 'm', ' ') if (d.minute > 0) else ('', '', '')
    secs = (d.second, 's', ' ') if (d.second > 0) else ('', '', '')
    time_format = days + hours + mins + secs
    format_str = '{}'*len(time_format)

    return format_str.format(*time_format)
```

I think there might be a better way to do the formatting to omit values that are zero instead of combining tuples and exploding them in the format string.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like the `datetime` module isn't really doing much to help you.  By using it, you avoid performing arithmetic and hard-coding constants `86400`, `3600`, and `60`.  However, in exchange, you end up hard-coding the accessors `.day`, `.hour`, `.minute`, and `.second`, in such a way that you have to write similar code four times, with no easy way to generalize them.  Attempts at generalization are further complicated by the fact that you need `d.day-1`, due to the way that you have abused `datetime` addition as a trick to convert the `timedelta` object into a `datetime` object.

Your output includes a trailing space, which I consider to be an annoyance.  One way to avoid that would be to use [`' '.join(…)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).  On the other hand, if `sec` is `0`, then the function would return an empty string, which is also unintuitive.  I would prefer `0s` as output in that special case.

In my opinion, you would be no worse off doing all of the arithmetic and formatting yourself, without the use of the `datetime` module.

```
def format_seconds(sec):
    def repeatedly(f, xs, n):
        for x in xs:
            m, n = f(n, x)
            yield m
    return ' '.join(
        '{}{}'.format(n, unit)
        for n, unit in zip(
            repeatedly(divmod, [86400, 3600, 60, 1], sec),
            'dhms'
        )
        if n
    ) or '0s'
```